# How do you make a discord bot respond to a back-and-forth?

Tags: python, discord, bots

How do you make a bot respond to a message and ask a question, like

Me:!guess 10

bot: pick a number between 1 and 10

me: 4

bot: incorrect, it was 5!

I can't figure out how to do this,
because once you respond to a command, I don't know how to have something like a global variable to save the answer.

Comment: do you have any code we can add to?

Comment: Uh, no, but I was asking how to do it in general.

Comment: Ive added some code, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some code I used, hopefully this will help, this give you 5 guesses to get it right and it gives you hints with bigger and expands on what you wanted, so you could adapt it if you don't want the bigger and smaller!

```
@commands.command()
async def game(self, ctx):
    number = random.randint(0, 100)
    for i in range(0, 5):
        await ctx.send('guess')
        response = await self.bot.wait_for('message')
        guess = int(response.content)
        if guess > number:
            await ctx.send('bigger')
        elif guess < number:
            await ctx.send('smaller')
        else:
            await ctx.send('yes!')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll add this to my bot. Is there any way that I can have it wait for a particular message?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could, however it would be changed on line 6 of the code